# React state not displaying appropriately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, axios

My issue: My state sometimes displays, if I refresh the browser, update code I get the following error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'country')` I am not sure why this behaviour occurs. In one instance it displays and another time it doesn't. Any explanation and solution would be appreciated.

My response returns a 200 status code and all the appropriate data that I console.log is legit so I am confused why this issue occurs.

---

App.js

```
import api from './api/fetchCovidData'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const  App = () => {
  const [covid, setCovidData] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCovidData = async () => {
      try{
        const response = await api.get('/cases?country=France');
        console.log(response.data)
        setCovidData(response.data);
      } catch (err) {
        if (err.response){
          // Not in the 200 response range
          console.log(err.response.data);
          console.log(err.response.status);
          console.log(err.response.headers);
        } else {
          console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`);
        }
      }
    }
    fetchCovidData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{covid.All.country}</h1>
      <h1>{covid.All.population}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

fetchCovidData.js

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://covid-api.mmediagroup.fr/v1'
});
```

---

Example Response

```
{
  "All": {
    "confirmed": 2604595,
    "recovered": 195365,
    "deaths": 62548,
    "country": "France",
    "population": 64979548,
    "sq_km_area": 551500,
    "life_expectancy": "78.8",
    "elevation_in_meters": 375,
    "continent": "Europe",
    "abbreviation": "FR",
    "location": "Western Europe",
    "iso": 250,
    "capital_city": "Paris",
    "lat": "46.2276",
    "long": "2.2137",
    "updated": "2020/12/26 12:21:56+00"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that your initial state is an empty object:

```
const [covid, setCovidData] = useState({});
```

But you are attempting to reference a level too deep on the initial render ***before*** your state is *really* populated:

```
<div>
  <h1>{covid.All.country}</h1>
  <h1>{covid.All.population}</h1>
</div>
```

Here `covid` is the empty object (`{}`), and accessing into `covid.All` is ok since it returns `undefined`, but when you then attempt to access into `covid.All.country`, well now you are attempting to access a property of an undefined object and the error is thrown (*i.e. `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'country')`*).

## Solutions

1. Provide valid initial state

   ```
   const [covid, setCovidData] = useState({ All: {} });
   ```
2. Use [Optional Chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to handle null checks

   ```
   <div>
     <h1>{covid.All?.country}</h1>
     <h1>{covid.All?.population}</h1>
   </div>
   ```
3. Use conventional null checks/guard clauses

   ```
   <div>
     <h1>{covid.All && covid.All.country}</h1>
     <h1>{covid.All && covid.All.population}</h1>
   </div>
   ```
4. Use conditional rendering

   ```
   <div>
     {covid.All && (
       <h1>{covid.All.country}</h1>
       <h1>{covid.All.population}</h1>
     )}
   </div>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is your initial state is empty. So, you have to check the state is empty/undefined/null or not before going to use.

```
return (
    covid && covid.All && (<div>
      <h1>{covid.All.country}</h1>
      <h1>{covid.All.population}</h1>
    </div>)
  )
```

or

```
<div>
   <h1>{covid?.All?.country}</h1>
   <h1>{covid?.All?.population}</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add question mark to validate if exist {covid?.All?.country} another option is to make a conditional

```js
return (
        covid && (<div>
          <h1>{covid?.All?.country}</h1>
          <h1>{covid?.All?.population}</h1>
        </div>)
      )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import api from './api/fetchCovidData'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const  App = () => {
  const [covid, setCovidData] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCovidData = async () => {
      try{
        const response = await api.get('/cases?country=France');
        console.log(response.data)
        setCovidData(response.data);
      } catch (err) {
        if (err.response){
          // Not in the 200 response range
          console.log(err.response.data);
          console.log(err.response.status);
          console.log(err.response.headers);
        } else {
          console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`);
        }
      }
    }
    fetchCovidData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{covid?.All?.country}</h1>
      <h1>{covid?.All?.population}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```